# How Detect if player wear a specific T-Shirt When he Touch a Brick [Roblox - LUA]

Tags: lua, roblox

Like in the title, i am looking for a script that can do that. If someone can repair this script I'll be happy :D

```
function onTouched(part)
local h = part.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
if h ~= nil then
    if player.parent.torso.roblox.Texture == "https://web.roblox.com/Bloxxer-item?id=1028595" then
        script.Parent.Check.Transparency = 0
        wait (2)
        script.Parent.Check.Transparency = 1
    end
end
```

end
script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouched)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot find any [free-model](https://www.roblox.com/develop/library?Keyword=t-shirt%20door&Category=6) that either does what you want, or are editable; here we go:

Because we are referencing `script.Parent` often, lets make a [variable](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Variable):

```
local Block = script.Parent
```

Also lets avoid putting constants like urls in the code body by making variable for that too:

```
local TShirtTexture = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?version=1&id=1028594"
```

Note that the t-shirt texture link differs from the item link. I think the [Bloxxer](https://web.roblox.com/Bloxxer-item?id=1028595) texture is `http://www.roblox.com/asset/?version=1&id=1028594`. To find the link, join the game in studio with the t-shirt on and [inspect](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Properties_panel) the t-shirt

We also need a [debouncer](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Debounce)

Then i like [anonymous functions](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Anonymous_function) better if you do not really need to reference it outside:

```
Block.Touched:connect(function(Part)
    -- code goes here
end)
```

The line `part.Parent:findFirstChild` might be unsafe as `part.Parent` might be `nil` if the part was removed after touching but before the code runs, so it is best to check it first (some VIP doors used to break if you shoot at them because of this). Same with the other stuff, check that it exists, else the code might break at some point.

Next, the character `Torso` is capitalized. Also, the t-shirt is in the character, not the player. And throw in some variables

And finally everything together:

```
-- Put some variables
local Block = script.Parent
local TShirtTexture = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?version=1&id=1028594"

-- Debounce variable
local Debounce = false

-- Use anonymous function
Block.Touched:connect(function(Part)
    -- Assume that the Part is a BodyPart, thus the parent should be the character
    local Character = Part.Parent

    -- Ensure that our assumption is correct
    if Character == nil or Character:findFirstChild("Humanoid") == nil then return end

    -- Reference to the assumed Torso
    local Torso = Character:findFirstChild("Torso")

    -- Ensure that it exists
    if Torso == nil then return end

    -- Reference to the assumed T-Shirt
    local TShirt = Torso:findFirstChild("roblox")

    -- Ensure that it exists, and that it is a Decal (T-Shirts are decals)
    if TShirt == nil or not TShirt:IsA("Decal") then return end

    -- Ensure the texture is correct
    if TShirt.Texture ~= TShirtTexture then return end

    -- Check debounce
    if Debounce then return end
    Debounce = true

    -- Do stuff
    Block.Check.Transparency = 0
    wait (2)
    Block.Check.Transparency = 1

    Debounce = false
end)
```

And if you want to check if the player owns the item, but not have to wear it, [check this out](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Restricted_door#Owning_a_certain_asset)

Also, if scripts does not work, remember to post relevant [errors](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Lua_errors)

Comment: I try it on my world and the script isn't working. I tried to change the T-Shirt ID a bit to see if the error was there but it's still not working.

Comment: @AirportStaff Any errors? Are the Block.Check correct? Normally you do not have Parts in Parts

Comment: I don't know why but someone edit my question and add a "Check" Because there weren't in my first question. But thanks anyways I remove the "Check" and now it's working!